# Is there a module to provide node access based on Ip address?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I am looking for a module that provides node access or content type access based on the ip address of the user? So what would be ideal is that i can select the ip address range allowed for a particular node when creating it or i can define a range of ip address on a content type.

Once i select the ip address range then someone coming from outside of that range should not be able to access that page.

I have looked into several modules and couldn't find much. The closest thing i found is in sandbox https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/schlicki/1461406

Please let me know if i can clarify more?

Answer (score 0):

The [Restrict IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_ip)  module is what you're looking for.

> This module allows administrators to restrict access to the site to an administrator defined set of IP addresses.
>
> Anyone trying to access the site from an IP address not in the list of allowed IP addresses will be redirected to an access denied page with the message "Your address is not in the list of allowed IP addresses". No blocks will be rendered, and no javascript will be added to the page. This will happen for any and all pages these users try to access.